# How to determine available heap memory in a C program

Tags: c, linux, memory, malloc

I want to write a program that will allocate some chunk of memory every second, and then write out how much memory is left (I intentionally do not free any memory as the actual use case for this is simulating out of memory situations). Here is the program (for linux):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    size_t mbs = 500 * 1000000; // 500mb

    while(true) {
        sleep(1);

        void* tmp = malloc(mbs);

        system("free");
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

The system call to `free` lists out the available memory, and it was my expectation that the available memory would decrease every second by the 500mb I am trying to allocate, however as can be seen in first few lines of output below, the available memory does not change in a significant way (out of around 32gb of RAM, the available memory hovers around 25gb). I have also tried lower amounts, 10mb and 100mb but the behavior is the same.
So in this particular output, by the time of the 8th free I would expect 8gbs of ram to be already used:

```
user@DESKTOP-DAGF175:/Projects/tmp$ g++ main.cpp
user@DESKTOP-DAGF175:/Projects/tmp$ ./a.out
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:       33471660     7338384    25903924       17720      229352    25999544
Swap:       8192000           0     8192000
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:       33471660     7330684    25911624       17720      229352    26007244
Swap:       8192000           0     8192000
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:       33471660     7327256    25915052       17720      229352    26010672
Swap:       8192000           0     8192000
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:       33471660     7325428    25916880       17720      229352    26012500
Swap:       8192000           0     8192000
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:       33471660     7325208    25917100       17720      229352    26012720
Swap:       8192000           0     8192000
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:       33471660     7321232    25921076       17720      229352    26016696
Swap:       8192000           0     8192000
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:       33471660     7321360    25920948       17720      229352    26016568
Swap:       8192000           0     8192000
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:       33471660     7318624    25923684       17720      229352    26019304
Swap:       8192000           0     8192000
```

I have also tried a similar thing on windows, but the result is the same. Here is also the windows code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main() {
    size_t mbs = 500 * 1000000; // 500mb

    while(true) {
        Sleep(2);

        void* tmp = malloc(mbs);

        system("systeminfo |find \"Available Physical Memory\"");
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Why am I not seeing a decrease in consumed memory?

Comment: Try writing something non-zero to the memory, in case it's lazily allocated on the first write. Also, note that there's likely no hard limit on used memory, since before you use up all of the swap, your system will slow down to a crawl.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The behaviour you are observing is due to the way modern operating systems handle memory allocations. When you request memory using `malloc()`, the operating system reserves virtual memory addresses **but doesn't immediately allocate physical memory pages**.

Only when the program writes to the memory will the operating system map those virtual addresses to physical memory pages.

This behaviour is called ***lazy allocation*** or ***overcommitment***. The OS promises the process some memory without really giving it until it is absolutely necessary.

If you want to observe a decrease in the available memory, you need to force the operating system to commit those pages by writing to the allocated memory:

```
const int PAGE_SIZE = 4096; // commonly used page size

int main() {
    size_t mbs = 500 * 1000000; // 500mb

    while(true) {
        sleep(1);

        char* tmp = (char*)malloc(mbs);
        if(tmp == NULL) {
            printf("Allocation failed\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        // Force the OS to commit the memory by writing to it
        for(size_t i = 0; i < mbs; i += PAGE_SIZE) {
            tmp[i] = 0;
        }

        system("free");
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

**Edit:** Also, you can disable overcommitment in Linux using `sysctl` interface:

```bash
echo 2 > /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory
```

Valid settings:

- `0` for heuristic strategy (the kernel will try to estimate the amount of free memory on userspace allocation)
- `1` for "always overcommit" (the kernel permits all memory allocations, regardless of the current memory allocation state)
- `2` for disabling overcommit

Comment: *If you want to observe a decrease in the available memory* Or you can disable memory overcommit and force the OS to not give out memory without committing to allowing its use.  *The OS promises the process some memory without really giving it until it is absolutely necessary*  Yep, and if you use it you can get, "HA HA! I LIED!  YOU CAN'T REALLY HAVE THAT MEMORY I PROMISED YOU!  IT'S THE OOM KILLER FOR YOU!!!"  If you're lucky it's your process.  If you're unlucky it's the main production database process or similar.  Memory overcommit is crazy stupid if you care about sustained availability.

Comment: I'm with Andrew here. The OS, like a budget airline just one engine failure away from bankruptcy, can and will lie about a lot of things, especially how much memory it can commit to allocating. When it gets caught in a lie, it just terminates the program that pointed out the problem, which solves the problem!

Comment: @tadman *When it gets caught in a lie, it just terminates the program that pointed out the problem...*  That's the problem - the Linux OOM killer **doesn't** necessarily terminate the program that pointed out the problem - if your critical production process uses 120 GB of your system's 128 GB of RAM and you log on and fire up Eclipse on that server by mistake, the OOM killer is likely to whack your production process.  Also see [Out-Of-Fuel Killer](https://lwn.net/Articles/104185/).  How'd you like flying on a plane that tossed you out a door if fuel got low?  Welcome to Linux.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Linux does get a bit murdery when low on memory, it's true. I've seen it kill all sorts of things in a psychopathic rage, including, inexplicably, `init`, but what's a little collateral damage when you can rest easy knowing there's lots of free memory.

Comment: @miloserdow I never got a coupon from OOMKiller. Only pages and angry customers.

Comment: If airlines operated like our OS, the moment the plane runs low on snacks, the least important passenger would be gently ejected out with a parachute and a coupon for a free meal on their next flight :)

I actually prefer comparing it to airlines overbooking tickets. Sure, it's a hassle when everyone turns up, but there's a reason they still do it. It genuinely helps with higher resource utilisation. It's all about efficiency!

Comment: @miloserdow You wouldn't want your bank or stock brokerage service to run like that, would you?  Or the computer controlling your CT scanner?  Not every system should be aiming for the most efficient use of RAM.  If you want **real** reliability and availability your kernel will only hand out memory if it **knows** it can support the process actually using **all** of the memory requested, no matter how far off in the future.  Any process asking for more memory than is available gets `ENOMEM`.  Any process designed with reliability and availability in mind will work just fine.

Comment: (cont)  If a product can't run under those conditions, it's garbage and has no place in a system that really cares about reliability and availability - drop it and find something better.

Comment: @AndrewHenle, sure, different environments require different strategies. I added information to my answer on controlling overcommit strategies in Linux.